# css less font-size addition or subtraction

Tags: css, less

Using `LESS` is there a way I can set a base font-size and then reference it later and output it say `1em` smaller? Ex:

```
@font-size: 3.025em;
```

And then in a media query or something:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    .box {
        font-size: @font-size - 1em;
    }
}
```

I tried googling this but wasn't coming up with anything.

Comment: Have you tried this? It should work fine. Are you having an actual problem, or are you asking if it's possible?

Comment: I should've just tried it ha, I didn't know it was possible. Is there a way to do it if the font-size wasn't defined ever? If the base font-size of an element was set manually and you want to subtract a value?

Comment: In answer to the question in your comment, "No." At present, LESS cannot read property values (so it cannot tell if, say `font-size: 12px` was set on `.box` at some point previously, or that such was set on `body` and inherited by `.box`). Also, LESS, being a CSS preprocessor, generally will never have knowledge of the browser environment, so it would not know if the browser was setting some value for `font-size` that was then the baseline for `.box`, nor would it have access to that value to subtract anything from it. As noted, what you have above works.

Comment: The user never apparently tried to run the code to begin with (based on the comment), and thus the question really was no question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. You must set the baseline font size as `LESS` won't be able to infer what the default is:

```
@font-size: 3.025em;
```

And then in a media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    .box {
        font-size: @font-size - 1em;
    }
}
```

;)